# Passing data among controllers

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS I have two controllers. One is responsible for handling data about people. The other controller is used to handle information about how the person data is displayed:

```
.controller('PersonCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function ($rootscope, $scope)
  {
    $scope.Persons = ['John', 'Mike'];
  } ]);


.controller('WidgetCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.myWidgets = {
            '1': {
                id: '1',
                name: 'Home',
                widgets: [{
                    col: 0,
                    row: 0,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "John"
                }, {
                    col: 2,
                    row: 1,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "Mike"
                }]
            }
        };
```

Notice in the PersonCtrl, I have two names: John and Mike. In the WidgetCtrl, I want to attach those names to the name field (in the example below, I just typed it in so that it's obvious where the data goes). How do I do this?

Comment: use services/factory for data sharing.. or pass the id of the entry that you want to use in other controller as routeParam

Comment: Use service to get the names for both the controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to elaborate the comment... you can use services to share data between controllers. check out [this video from egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

egghead.io is an excellent resource for starting with angualrjs.

this is how that service should look like

```
app.service('productService', function() {
  var personList = [];

  var add = function(newObj) {
      personList.push(newObj);
  }

  var get = function(){
      return personList;
  }

  return {
    add: add,
    get: get
  };

});
```

**EDIT**

to address your comment on how to get names in widget

```
controller('WidgetCtrl', ['$scope', 'PersonService'
    function($scope, personService ) {

      /* init the myWidgets*/

      var count = 0;
      angular.forEach(personService.personList, function(item){
           $scope.myWidgets['1'].widgets[count].name = item.name;
            count = count +1;
      });
}]);
```

Comment: I don't see how this applies. Are you saying that I should use a service and that within that service I create my objects for storing the Person data and the Widget data? If so, I'm still not sure how the names get plugged into the myWidgets member.

Comment: this is answering your first question of how to get persons controller in widgetCtrl... i will edit answer to address second part

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking but I still see an issue with this. When you store the person's name from the personList into the name member of myWidgets, is this not just copying the name? What if the name changes in the service? Will this be automatically updated in the myWidgets? I have my doubts.

Comment: i guess that was the requirement.. "In the WidgetCtrl, I want to attach those names to the name field", in case you want to track name changes... then you will have setup a $watch on personList

Comment: You are gonna need to set this variable personList - there is no method in your service for this - only add and getProducts

Comment: @StenMuchow - i just gave example of service.. not implemented the service in actual. i guess that got the downvote :(

Comment: The answer is a bit contrived and also using a for loop when you should be using an angular.forEach loop - this will notify the scope of changes and induce a digest cycle...

Comment: @StenMuchow i used for-loop because i needed a counter... anyway updated the answer to use forEach for digest cycle, also changed the service implementation... is that ok now??

Comment: @HarishR just remember to use what is already given... index over another var count. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A controller is for mediation between a model (in its $scope) and the template. Sometimes nested controllers is the right way to do things, i.e. your WidgetCtrl assumes that it is inside a PersonCtrl. In this case it can access the parent controller scope members through the scope prototypical inheritance.

A more sophisticated way of doing it though is to use a service that deals with fetching data from a back end and presenting it to various controllers that may need it.

Comment: I know how to create a service and put that Persons data into it and access it in the WidgetsCtrl but what isn't clear is how in the WidgetsCtrl I actually assign those values to the "name" member. keep in mind that if the Person's name changes in one location, it has to update in all locations.

Comment: If WidgetCtrl is nested inside a PersonCtrl then $scope.Persons is available there as well as in the PersonCtrl instance. This is how scopes inherit from each other as they nest in the template.

Comment: But it's not nested and even if it were, I still don't see how the names from Persons get plugged in the name member of the myWidgets member.

Comment: If they're not nested then they need to interact through the service. After that it becomes a matter of how JavaScript references work. You'd probably want to change the models to use objects for each person in the service and then you can have a reference to this model in the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to share data between controllers - events, services and controller inheritance through the use of parent controllers.

There is no right or wrong way, but typically if you are fetching data from a server then a service is the way forward. If you wanna utilize the observer pattern aka pub/sub then use events. We use multiple solutions in our spa.

This however looks like the job for a service - especially since you say one is responsible for showing data - aka the truth - aka a controller (widget). The other is responsible for handling data about a person - use a service which returns the array you need.

Service example:

```
.factory('persons', function() {

  var persons = ['john', 'mike'];

  function getPersons() {
    return persons;
  }

  return {
    getPersons: getPersons
  }

});
```

Some ex HTML for the update:

```
<button ng-click="updateWidget(getPeople())">Update Widget</button>
```

Your Controller:

```
.controller('WidgetCtrl', ['$scope', 'persons'
    function($scope, persons) {

        //Both not used only for example purposes...

        var peeps = [];             
        peeps = $scope.getPeople();


        //Now in yer HTM you can pass this function into the updateWidget fct
        // ex <button ng-click="updateWidget(getPeople())">Update Widget</button>

        $scope.getPeople = function() {
        // Now this is not async but be away in the future if you req from server you need to use promises
           return persons.getPersons();
        }




       $scope.updateWidget = function(people) {

         var item = $scope.myWidgets[1].widgets;

              angular.forEach(items, function(item, $index) {

                 item.name = people[$index];
             });
      }                   

        $scope.myWidgets = {
            '1': {
                id: '1',
                name: 'Home',
                widgets: [{
                    col: 0,
                    row: 0,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "X"
                }, {
                    col: 2,
                    row: 1,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "Y"
                }]
            }
        };
```

Comment: Even if I use a service to retrieve the data, I still need to plug those names into some structure that also contains UI stuff. For example, the name has to appear in an exact location on the screen and that location is what the widgets.col and widgets.row specify. So are you saying include the UI stuff as part of the Person stuff in a single structure and when I retrieve the names of persons I need to programmatically stuff the names into the structure?

Comment: how does the person array become populated is it static or dynamic?

Comment: Well currently I'm just hardcoding that for testing purposes. Later however, they will be retrieved from the server.

Comment: But you didn't explain how to get the names into myWidgets. @HarishR shows how that is done only I have a question on whether the names will get updated in myWidget if they change in the service.

Comment: Not sure why you show "X" and "Y" as names. The names have to come from the people variable that you created, which means that you have to copy them to each member in myWidgets.

Comment: If you pay attention to the code i wrote it is to show that yes they will be x and y to begin with but when u fire the update widget button the names will be updated and the scope as well!